# Selenium webdriver autocomplete

Tags: selenium, autocomplete, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have input like

```
<input id="idForm:j_idt21Input" class="rf-sel-inp" type="text" value="Начните ввод" name="idForm:j_idt21Input" autocomplete="off">
```

and divs with variants

```
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Items">
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item0" class="rf-sel-opt">Все</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item1" class="rf-sel-opt">Domosti Main (Domosti Main)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item2" class="rf-sel-opt rf-sel-sel">N&K (N&K)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item3" class="rf-sel-opt">АГМ (АГМ)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item4" class="rf-sel-opt">АЕС Групп (АЕС Групп)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item5" class="rf-sel-opt">АРКО (АРКО)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item6" class="rf-sel-opt">АТМ-комплект (АТМ-комплект)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item7" class="rf-sel-opt">Авита (Авита)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item8" class="rf-sel-opt">Аква С. (Аква С.)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item9" class="rf-sel-opt">Акваарт-М (Акваарт-М)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item10" class="rf-sel-opt">Актив групп (Актив групп)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item11" class="rf-sel-opt">Алан-Трейд (Алан-Трейд)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item12" class="rf-sel-opt">Алекон (Алекон)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item13" class="rf-sel-opt">Алекс трейд (Алекс трейд)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item14" class="rf-sel-opt">Альт-М (Альт-М)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item15" class="rf-sel-opt">Альфа (Альфа)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item16" class="rf-sel-opt">Ансан (Ансан)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item17" class="rf-sel-opt">Ария Текстиль (Ария Текстиль)</div>
<div id="idForm:j_idt21Item18" class="rf-sel-opt">Арреал 2000 (Арреал 2000)</div>
</div>
```

I tried

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Поставщики']/following-sibling::td//input[contains(@id, 'Input')]")).sendKeys("Поливалент");
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Поставщики']/following-sibling::td//input[contains(@id, 'Input')]")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Поставщики']/following-sibling::td//input[contains(@id, 'Input')]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

but it's not working

Help, how to select variant from this input with selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

try this variant(using css selector):

```
webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.rf-sel-inp")).sendKeys("Поливалент");
```

or another way using jscript :

```
String cssSelector = ....  //css selector of the element u need to select
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssSelector+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Ok. What do you use to locate needed element in DOM? 
Try next thing. Install firepath (addon to firebug in firefox) and enter there  
input.rf-sel-inp    
It is vital to know whether you pass proper locator to driver.
Is element (input field) pointed  out in the DOM  ?

Comment: As I understood you need to  enter somthing in input field, right?
this must work:
String properCssSelector =  ....//proper css selector
webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(properCssSelector)).clear();
webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(properCssSelector)).sendKeys("blablabla");

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Начнитеввод']")).sendKeys("Поливалент");
```

Let me know if its not working!